# Absolute sine inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

How do I prove that
$$|\sin(10x)|\leq 10|\sin(x)|$$

for all real numbers $x$?

Comment: I plotted the difference in Wolfram Alpha and it holds there

Comment: what have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: We also have $\sin(10x)=2 \cos(x) (1 - 2 \cos(2 x) + 2 \cos(4 x)) (1 + 2 \cos(2 x) + 2 \cos(4 x)) \sin(x)$

Comment: So it remains to prove that $2|\cos(x)| |1-2\cos(2x)+2\cos(4x)| |1+2|\cos(2x)|+2|\cos(4x)|\leq 10$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

The easiest thing would be to prove by induction that $$|\sin(nx)|\leq n|\sin(x)|,$$
for all $n$.

Comment: Yes indeed.....